# CORS configuration in SXA

Tags: sxa

I'm trying to use the `CORS settings under Site Grouping`, but they don't seem to do anything.  I also can't seem to find any documentation about it.  Does anyone know of documentation or know what the secret is to get these to work?

I don't get any errors, they just don't seem to have any impact on the response headers in any way.  I have verified that the changes have been published properly.

This is the settings I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had raised a Sitecore support ticket for this same issue and below is the response that I got.

- Please find below the documentation of how to include credentials on cross-origin requests for an SXA site:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/include-credentials-on-cross-origin-requests.html

- CORS functionality in the SXA is based on the following article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api, where web service is SXA site and web client is created according to your needs.
- The CORS Settings (available in SXA site) only apply to SXA Data Modeling.
  You can find more information and samples about the SXA Data Modeling here:
  https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/16/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/introducing-sxa-data-modeling.html

To make the client communicate with the SXA site you should perform the following steps:

Create a page with the JSON component.

- Open page1 in the Experience Editor;
- Choose "JSON" device in the "Experience (tab)->Device";
- Add the necessary "JSON" component, for example, "JSON List". Please see the video for details: http://www.screencast.com/t/Fha6PWGB

Make a `JSON` device valid for correct resolving during the request from the client, for example, make a `JSON` device as default one or add some query string: https://www.screencast.com/t/0MYGLrwCS

Publish site;

- Create a client as described in the following article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api
- Set service URL on the client to the following one: 'http://SXA_Site_hostName/page1?device=1'. Please see the video for details: http://www.screencast.com/t/gPpqJj27t
- Each CORS entry (that is located under SXA site definition item: "/sitecore/content/New tenant/New site/Settings/Site Grouping/New site/CORS/default") defines a list of parameters that client must satisfy to access this particular site (an origin from where the request is accepted,  allowed request methods, allowed request headers, etc )

For example, if we change "Allow Origin" from "*" to "http://test", we will not be able to get a response from the server. Please see the video for details: http://www.screencast.com/t/MkSxzXP0

Answer (score -4):

The CORS is to configure cross domain request!! You will not get any error as it is not related to your domain and hosting setup, it will impact to other domain trying to access your APIs.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_entityservice_and_cors

https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

You can refer to below example for clear understanding and use of CORS.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I know what CORS is... the settings don't seem to work. My issue isn't that I don't know what to put in the setting, my issue is that no matter what I put in changes anything on the site.

Comment: To be specific... the Sitecore SXA settings under Site Grouping don't seem to work...

Comment: The original question was about using CORS in SXA, not about CORS itself. Please provide some input about how to make the CORS functionality work in SXA.

Comment: I might have miss understood the question? But you have asked for the documentation and purpose/use of cors in SXA.. so hope you have referred the links I have shared before commenting.. I might not satisfy your need but the document I have shared explain how and when to configure cros in SXA? I am sharing that link again for your reference. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_entityservice_and_cors.

Comment: Again, I am looking for documentation or help with the CORS settings under the SXA site grouping.  The documentation you are providing appears to me to be related to general Sitecore documentation and does not appear to relate to SXA at all.  Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't relate to my question at all.  I will update my question to include the fields in question.